# ArcGIS 10.1 SDE database schema other than SDE or DBO

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, sql-server

Just wondering if it's possible to apply a schema other than SDE or DBO to SDE feature or raster tables stored in an enterprise database on MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have got a new customise schema and want to apply it to a few of tables in the SDE database.

Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure, but I do have to stress that the SDE user should never be used for any of the business tables or feature classes.  The SDE user should be limited to owning the the underling SDE and GeoDatabase tables that are used in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a database connection as your desired user with the matching schema. Any data loaded or created will use the schema of your connected user. This same idea applies if you want a user other than SDE or DBO to own the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible

with ESRI ArcObjects you can use any type of data in it, provided you know the format. Please take a look on [PluginData Source](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/dotnet/f4ce6eb3-606c-4aa1-a7ba-28abaa81f930.htm)

With plugin data source you build your own driver to read data. Any type of data. Basically you write the logic telling your software, how to read the data.

The simple example would be a text file with some different separators containing information about lat and lng. You will build a plugin data source for this and whenever you use this data from ArcMap, ArcCatalog etc, you will see that file as a featureClass.

You can find a description [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/java/doc/6ff1b081-7713-4ae6-bdaa-883b196eac34.htm) and in above link also.